# How is this website accessing the Chrome menu

Tags: google-chrome, menu

Apparently this website: https://www.gizbot.com/internet/features/4-easy-ways-prevent-google-chrome-from-closing-the-tabs-036208.html is able to cause an extra item to appear in the Chrome menu:

[image: Chrome website access menu]

This menu-item is not there when I open the menu on any other tab.

Clicking this menu-item causes an app to be installed:

[image: Chrome app install dialog]

Now I have two questions:

- How do they do it? Is there some Chrome API call available to do this? Or does Chrome automatically look in the Chrome Web Store for related apps and then add this to the menu?
- How do I prevent this behavior?

The latter is the one I'm most interested in.